# D3: Issue with links not disappearing on removal

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've put together the following - http://jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/c48dt2kb/.

Key code here:

```
function generateNodes(p) {

    var node = svg.append("circle")
        .data([p])      
            .call(force.drag)           
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("r", 0.1)
            .transition()
            .attr("r", 5)
            .transition().delay(20000)
            .attr("r", 0.1)
            .style("opacity", 0.1)
            .remove()
            .each("end", function() {
                force.links().forEach(function(link, i) {
                    if (link.source == force.nodes()[0] || link.target == force.nodes()[0]) {
                        force.links().splice(i, 1)
                    }
                })
                svg.selectAll("line").data(force.links()).exit().remove()   
                force.nodes().shift()
            })

    force.nodes().push(p)

    generateLinks(p);

    force.start()
}
```

On mouse click a node is generated, if there are any other nodes within the radius of the "crosshair" they're linked to the node most recently generated. After 20000ms the nodes and links should disappear. Currently working fine for the nodes, not so fine for the links - they don't all remove when the associated nodes are removed. @Lars Kotthoff mentioned it's a bad idea to iterate over something and remove that something from within the iteration but 1> I can see no other way of achieving what I want and 2> if you're iterating over objects surely any issues with "skipping over" the things you're iterating is negated?

Comment: in the code you have a 20 second transition, in your question you have a 200 second transition... what are you after?

Comment: Apologies, that's a typo. Corrected. I want to understand how it is that certain links aren't disappearing with the logic I'm using.

Comment: Added force.start() directly after force.nodes().shift() above and it's now working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Would still be good to be given the all clear that when iterating over objects using forEach, you can remove the object from within the iteration without any negative effect on the iterative process. To elaborate, I know that if you remove items from the thing over which you're iterating when using indexes, you will end up skipping over iterations if the dataset compacts when data is removed. Intuitively I don't think that's the case when iterating over objects as order is not relevent? Would be good to have that confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected your code, see http://jsfiddle.net/hxyyhu6b/1/

Main principle: each link gets id and is removed using id selector.

The remove function iterator now:

```
            .each("end", function(d) {
                for(var i= 0; i<force.links().length;){
                    var link = force.links()[i]
                    if ((link.source == d) || (link.target == d)) {
                        force.links().splice(i, 1)
                        svg.select("#" + link.id).remove()
                    }
                    else {i++}
                }
                force.nodes().splice(force.nodes().indexOf(d), 1)
            })
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I think my code was actually fine I just needed to add a force.start(). If iterating over objects I don't think it skips objects when you remove other objects from within the loop so it's ok to do? But thank you.